# How can I arrange this function so it returns a list with all this lists on it

Tags: python, list, file, tkinter

So I've been working on a project and I can only use Tkinter. The thing is that I need that this function that I found in someone else's question returns a list with the lists its already printing, but I can't find a way to make this happen. Currently it prints a list for every line there is in the .txt file and inside each list it has the words of the line its referring to. I need it to do that but all those lists that its printing should go inside one list. I am very new at this so sorry for the stupid question:

```
    def file_to_list(file):
        stop_words=open(file,'r') 
        lines = [line.split() for line in stop_words]
        for line in lines:
            print(line)
```

Comment: All those line are already in a big list called `lines`. Try printing that out and seeing what it shows.

Comment: Omg, yes, thank you so much, that worked. I feel so stupid XD

Comment: Actually you want a *`list of lists`* or *`list of all words`*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the answer

```
def file_to_list(file):
    stop_words=open(file,'r') 
    lines = [line.split() for line in stop_words]
    print(lines)
```

Comment: Yes! I feel so stupid. Thank you so much!!

Comment: no problem buddy , we all learn the same way